# Add a symbol list to a manual written in LuaLaTeX

Tags: symbols

I am currently writing a manual using LuaLaTeX (UTF-8) and would like to include the following symbols in my document, with the description on the right:

[image]

Currently I'm changing the layout in a Word file and copying the image as a figure into my document, however I would like to be able to write this in my code for future documents and be able to change the parameters.

Does anyone have a good idea on how to do this, perhaps using a certain package?

I do apologize for the very basic question, I'm rather new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also play with the `\fboxsep` length.

```
\documentclass[border=.1in]{standalone}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}

\begin{document}
\fbox{T} \fbox{PCR}
\fbox{\makebox[.5in]{wide}}
\fbox{\hspace{1em}wider\hspace{1em}} baseline text.
\end{document}
```

[image: fbox test]

You can create a double box by slightly overlapping two boxes.  The `\vphantom` is used to force both boxes to be the exact same height.  A `\strut` would also work, but adds room for descenders.

```
\documentclass[border=.1in]{standalone}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}

\newcommand{\doublebox}[2]{\fbox{#1\vphantom{#2}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\vphantom{#1}#2}}

\begin{document}
\doublebox{Double}{Box}
\end{document}
```

[image: double box]

The following code provides the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}

\newcommand{\doublebox}[2]{\fbox{#1\vphantom{#2}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}\fbox{\vphantom{#1}#2}}

\begin{document}

\setarraylength

\begin{tabular}{cl}

\doublebox{AR}{1} & Amplification Reagent 1\\[0.5cm]
\fbox{T} & Taq DNA polymerase\\[0.5cm]
\fbox{UPM} & Universal PCR Mix\\[0.5cm]
\doublebox{PCR}{p7} & PCR p7 Primer Mix\\

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: This function can make the boxes so this definitely helps, but how can I align the text after the boxes (as in the figure) and how can I make a box divided in two?

Comment: If you mean the horizontal alignment shown, you can use \begin{tabular}{cl} ...

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I needed. Mind if I put the final output in your answer?